# Is it possible to log on to a Windows Domain account using a finger print reader in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, security

**Is it possible to log on to a Windows Domain account using a finger print reader in Windows 7**?

I've had conflicting feedback over whether this is possible.

If anyone has had success with this, please share the model information of the scanner you've used and the method in which it was accomplished. I would be greatly appreciative of any advice.

Comment: Windows 7 does not have native support for biometric logins - fingerprint scanner vendors have to create their own support for this function.  Sometimes these applications simply map a fingerprint to a password, which which case a domain login would be possible.  Others, however, may implement matching at a deeper level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using lenovo thinkpad, and I followed the steps mentioned over here. http://www.technlg.net/windows/fingerprint-logon-windows-7/

I am able to login to domain account with finger scan.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an Acer Travelmate TM8371G with a EgisTec reader built in (1C7A:0801).  This comes with biometric software (so isn't native), with which I use to log into a domain account with a swipe of my finger.

Running Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from a [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b8f4c4a-19ae-42a6-b3a3-35b74fa75838/fingerprint-logon-and-domains) from someone who got it working:

> I had the same problem (but with a ThinkPad w500) on Win7 RC1. The problem is actually quite simple to solve, once you know where to look of course... ;)
>
> It does not involve Group Policy settings - even though the setting can be controlled via that approach, but its not per default.
>
> Goto: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Biometric Devices
>
> Click: Change Biometric Settings
>
> Click both: 
>   Allow users to log on to Windowsd using their fingerprints
>   and 
>   Allow users to log on to a domain using their fingerprints
>   Restart the computer.
>
> Click: 'Switch user' at the log on screen and choose the fingerprint icon (this of course requires you to first have added a set of fingerprints to your account)
>
> Swipe your finger. At this point nothing happens (or at least it didn't for me). The screen remained active with the fingerprint icon and a password field.
>
> Now type your password and your'e logged on (I guess this i a final security measure to validate the account against the AD). 
>   Now restart your computer and voila! your fingerprint is accepted and password no longer required.
>
> Hope this helpes...